# Perl regex: How to capture groups in piped text?

Tags: regex, perl, pipe, regex-group

I expected the output of

```
echo "(a b c)(a b c)" | perl -ne "/(a) b/g; print $1"
```

to be:

```
aa
```

since $1 refers to the first captured group, which happens to be "a".

However the above code outputs :

```
(a b c)(a b c)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First use single quotes under *nix, as this is not what you want:

```
echo "(a b c)(a b c)" | perl -MO=Deparse -ne "/(a) b/g; print $1"
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
  /(a) b/g;
  print $_;
}
```

and then use scalar context with `/g` to iterate over all matches

```
echo "(a b c)(a b c)" | perl -ne 'print $1 while /(a) b/g'
```

or use list context so regex returns all matches at once,

```
echo "(a b c)(a b c)" | perl -ne 'print /(a) b/g'
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense now, thanks!
And extra thanks for teaching me the Deparse trick!!
(I can't up-vote yet due to bad reputation ...)